# Datetimepicker from to validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I use datetimepicker of https://gijgo.com/ and I want to make a from to validation system in it.

I tried to set the maxDate and minDate, but then I saw that datetimepicker doesn't have that configuration: https://gijgo.com/datetimepicker/configuration

```
$(function () {
    $("#startdate").datetimepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM',
        modal: true,
        footer: true,
        maxDate: function () {
            var date = new Date(val.end_date);
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
            return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        }
    });
    $("#enddate").datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM',
        modal: true,
        footer: true,
        minDate: function () {
            var date = new Date(val.start_date);
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you could utilize the `change` event and write your custom validation there https://gijgo.com/datetimepicker/events/change

Comment: I saw that too, but I still the from to validation function.

Comment: looking at the example `change: function (e) { alert('Change is fired'); }`, you should be able to get the selected date/time via `e` (maybe `e.value`, but debugging this via Dev Tools in your browser will be a lot easier) and then determine if this is inside/outside of your valid range, and then either accept the value or set the value to `''` and alert the user. In order to help you debug further, please put this into a jsfiddle so we can play around with a live example.

Comment: It isn't that easy

Comment: Are you saying the `change` function and reading `e` isn't that easy? Or putting this in a jsfiddle? You're going to need to much more specific than "it isn't that easy" for additional help.

Comment: I just need help with creating that function with this library. Because I don't know anymore where to begin with. This is so confusing.